# keep only white-listed elements and/or attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file with a plethora of nodes, each having a vast amount of attributes. For simplicity, let us assume the XML looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <header />
  <group>
     <node1 attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z" />
     <node2 attr4="x" attr5="y" attr6="z" />
     <node3 attr7="x" attr8="y" attr9="z" />
     <node1 attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z" />
  </group>
</root>
```

I would like to reduce this XML into a smaller version by reducing the content of `/root/group/` by eliminating both attributes as well as nodes.

- all nodes with name `node3` should be removed
- The nodes with name `node1` should only have attribute `attr1`
- The nodes with name `node2` should only have attributes `attr5` and `attr6`

I could write a simple XSLT for this by making use of simple *if-match-do-nothing*, eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/root/group/node3" />
   <xsl:template match="/root/group/node1/@attr2" />
   <xsl:template match="/root/group/node1/@attr3" />
   <xsl:template match="/root/group/node2/@attr4" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This, however, does not fit my needs. The above states what I do not want, but I would like to state what I do want by making use of a [whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting) Two questions I found answered this question partially. [One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790031) introduced the whitelist for the nodes, the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820874) introduced the whitelist for the attributes. How can I do this elegantly in a single whitelist or is there a better method? Can this be done in a whitelist of the form:

```
<whitelist>
  <node1 attr1="" />
  <node2 attr5="" attr6="" />
</whitelist>
```

**Remark:** I can only use XSLT-1.0

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <header />
  <group>
     <node1 attr1="x" />
     <node2 attr5="y" attr6="z" />
     <node1 attr1="x" />
  </group>
</root>
```

---

**relevant questions:**

- [XSLT - How to keep only wanted elements from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790031)
- [XSL : Copy Attributes That Match A Whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820874)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do it for you? Have a single template that match children of the `group` elements, and then check the white list document to see whether to copy that node, and if so, what attributes should be copied too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="ns" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <ns:WhiteList>
        <node>
            <name>node1</name>
            <attr>attr1</attr>
        </node>
        <node>
            <name>node2</name>
            <attr>attr5</attr>
            <attr>attr6</attr>
        </node>
    </ns:WhiteList>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group/*">
        <xsl:variable name="node" select="document('')//ns:WhiteList/node[name = name(current())]" />
        <xsl:if test="$node">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() = $node/attr]|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to make your stylesheet itself be the "whitelist":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node1 | node2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@attr1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@attr5 | @attr6"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Otherwise it can get pretty complicated:

- It's relatively easy to test if a node appears in the given whitelist by its **name** (as they do on the other questions you linked to);
- It is not so easy - esp. in XSLT 1.0 - to see if the node appears at the same **position** in the tree's hierarchy (i.e. that the **path** to it is the same as the path to a node in the whitelist).

If it's sufficient to test by name only, then you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:whitelist>
    <root>
        <header/>
        <group>
            <node1 attr1=""/>
            <node2 attr5="" attr6=""/>
        </group>
    </root>
</my:whitelist>

<xsl:variable name="whitelist" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:whitelist"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="$whitelist//*[name() = name(current())]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="$whitelist//@*[name() = name(current())]">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But then of course you could simplify the structure of the whitelist, since it's completely ignored.

---

For an example of how this could be done with a whitelist consisting of **paths**, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276667/3016153

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you did here but I'm wondering how you match the attributes. I was expecting to see a check also on the parent of the attributes.

Comment: As I said, the test is done by name only. It does not check the parent of the element nor the parent of the attribute.