# XSLT element whitelist

Tags: xml, xslt, whitelist

I've started using XSLT (6 month newbie), and are trying to understand utilizing a whitelist of elements to a large XML file to only keep elements in the whitelist.

The irony is I have been running a previous XSLT that is simply a large list of what not to include.
Through posts here i can see if i had just been looking at what elements too keep, the list would be far easier to maintain.

[keep only white-listed elements and/or attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420288/keep-only-white-listed-elements-and-or-attributes)

[XSLT - How to keep only wanted elements from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790031/xslt-how-to-keep-only-wanted-elements-from-xml)

I am using Saxon-HE 9.9.1.1N.

Here is a slimmed down version of my XML, where I do not want to keep the **type** & **brand** elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlatTable>
   <Table>
      <type>1</type>
      <ID>0001</ID>
      <Brand>0</Brand>
      <Name>Test 1</Name>
      <code>X7F7</code>
   </Table>
   <Table>
      <type>1</type>
      <ID>0002</ID>
      <Brand>0</Brand>
      <Name>Test 2</Name>
      <code>X7F5</code>
   </Table>
</FlatTable>
```

The expected output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlatTable>
   <Table>
      <ID>0001</ID>
      <Name>Test 1</Name>
      <code>X7F7</code>
   </Table>
   <Table>
      <ID>0002</ID>
      <Name>Test 2</Name>
      <code>X7F5</code>
   </Table>
</FlatTable>
```

I'm trying to utilise the solution that *Dimitre Novatchev* supplied here but can not for the life of me see where I'm screwing it up:
[XSLT - How to keep only wanted elements from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790031/xslt-how-to-keep-only-wanted-elements-from-xml)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns="some:ns">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <ns:WhiteList>
  <name>ID</name>
  <name>Name</name>
  <name>code</name>
 </ns:WhiteList>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The text says " I do not want to keep the type & brand elements": for that with XSLT 3 using `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` plus `<xsl:template match="type | Brand"/>` would suffice. You could even use a static parameter and a shadow attribute to parameterize the approach if needed. The code you then show tries a completely different approach and XSLT 1, it is not clear why you use `ns:ID`, i.e. a prefix there, while the input sample doesn't seem to use a namespace.

Comment: I have to admit Martin, thats an error and i will fix the `ns:ID` . My whitelist could be up to 100 fields, thus why I'm looking at this way, or any method using XSLT 1,2 but preferably 3. (I'm trying to learn XSLT3)

Comment: In XSLT 2 and later there is certainly no need to use a top-level element like `ns:WhiteList` as a container and the `document('')` approach, a simple parameter or variable would suffice to list element names, or a sequence of strings or QNames.

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting to learn Martin. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the white list in XSLT 2 or 3 can simply be stored in a parameter or variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="white-list"
    as="xs:string*" select="'ID', 'Name', 'code'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=$white-list])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRApn